# How to Access Internet Explorer on ubuntu or online?

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, search, browser

I go through browserstack ,browserling but their display limited access ,so can any body have solution to access IE at on ubuntu or online at browser?

i have tried browserstack ,browserling

no code

browserstack ,browserling and also other provides limited access and also not giving into latest version

Answer (score 1):

MS provides free VM images for testing IE starting from version 8. You should install VM software to your Ubuntu system and then take the required image [from here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/).

Comment: Thanks for reply ,will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE browser do you want to install?

If you want to install the lower version, you could refer to [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingInternetExplorer) to using the Wine and cab extract components.

If you want to install the IE 9+ version, it is better to use create a [free Virtual Machines From IE8 to MS Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/).

Comment: Thanks for reply ,will try and let you know

Comment: i did with old version but my wine version is higher then IE version but after installing IE wine is crashed so i used higher version of  IE so same issue happen this time error return that IE version not supported.